# iOS Alarm Clock

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have created a simple alarm notification App through which I can get real time, set alarm on or off, and play a single tone audio. But I need to play a sound which should start with a class `VOID`.

Below is the code:

To get and start alarm notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    dateTimerPicker.date = [NSDate date];

}

- (void)presentMessage:(NSString *)message {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Hello!"
                          message:message
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}

- (void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!!";
    notification.soundName = @"PhoneOld.mp3";
    [self playPause];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}

- (IBAction)alarmSetOn:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTimerPicker.date];
    NSLog(@"Alarm Set: %@", dateTimeString);


    [self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:dateTimerPicker.date];
    [self presentMessage:@"Alarm ON!"];


}

- (IBAction)alarmSetOff:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Alarm Off");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [self presentMessage:@"Alarm OFF!"];
}
```

This is my VOID:

```
- (void)playPause {

    RADAppDelegate *appDelegate = (RADAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (appDelegate.radiosound == 0){

        [appDelegate.radiosound play];

    } else {

        [appDelegate.radiosound pause];

    }

}
```

How can I set the alarm to start playing the `radiosound` if is rated 0, like a:

```
notification.soundName = [self playPause];
```

But I know this is a `NSString`.

Comment: IMO cancel the scheduled notification and reschedule a new notification with `notification.soundName = radioSound;`

Comment: What's your question? How to play a streaming sound on a notification (you can't), how to have a notification call into your app (it won't, unless the user accepts the alert), how to play *any* sound on a notification (which Aniket answered below), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to assign a sound name to scheduled notification, just invoke the playPause method and get the name of sound file from notification, as shown below and just assign it to `NSString` and set property to it in **appDelegate** and access it  to play that file.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *nsStr_soundFile;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize nsStr_soundFile;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {


//Give call to play sound method.

self.nsStr_soundFile=notification.soundName;
    VOID *obj=[VOID alloc]init];
        [obj playPause];

}
```

Comment: Is not a Sound File,is a streaming audio, when the notification.soundName is called I'll try to start play with the last streaming setting.

Comment: Alarm notifications are very restricted things. You can't get them to magically play a streaming resource; look at the docs. It can either play a sound resource in your application's main bundle or a default sound.

Comment: ok theres a method to do that? i can rewrite all function no problem, but i need to a example for that, because is my first time to try a create an alarm clock.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a trick with opting out of iOS multitasking by setting in your app .plist file this key **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** to **YES** as written [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/)

> When an app opts out, it cycles between the not-running, inactive, and
>   active states and never enters the background or suspended states.
>
> An app that runs in the pre-multitasking compatibility mode keeps
>   running when the user locks the device while the app is in the
>   foreground. All the app has to do is wait for the alarm time and
>   execute its custom code.